# Using images as bullet points

Tags: html, css, sass

I am having a problem using images as bullet points- bullet points are positioned like I want with bullet points that have only one line of text, but when they have more than one line of text then bullet points don't start from the start, but in the middle. 
Is there any way around using weird image canvas hacks to position these 2 bullet points? Is the best solution to use another images (with huge bottom canvas for example) for these 2 bullets to fix this problem?

Here is what I am talking about:

Second bullet point is positioned incorrectly here:
[image: Second bullet point is positioned incorrectly here]
Last bullet point is positioned incorrectly here:
[image]

HTML:

```
<ul class="service-box__list">
              <li class="service-box__item">
                Võtame enda kanda kogu igapäevase kinnisvarahalduse, sh ka kõik omaniku kohustused;
              </li>
              <li class="service-box__item">
                Pakume kinnisvara korrashoidu, tarbimis (nt. elekter, küte, vesi, kanalisatsiooni ning kommunikatsioon)
                -ja tugiteenused (nt parkimiskorraldus, valvesüsteemid);
              </li>
              <li class="service-box__item">
                Dokumenteerimine objektiga seotud infovahetuse oma digitaalsesse andmebaasi;
              </li>
              <li class="service-box__item">
                Organiseerimine kõik vajalikud ehitus- ja remonditööd;
              </li>
              <li class="service-box__item">
                Koostame perioodilised eelarved ning aruandluse vastavalt Sinu äri vajadustele ja isikupäradele;
              </li>
              <li class="service-box__item">
                Viime läbi objektiga seonduvate andmete regulaarse analüüsi, et parandada hoone võtmenäitajaid.
              </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
&__list {
    list-style: none;
}

&__item {
    font-size: $default-font-size;
    background: url('./../img/roheline-leht-2.png') no-repeat left;
    padding-left: 2.5rem;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [list-style-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image)

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('image.png');
}
```

In your example:

```
.service-box__list {
    list-style-image: url('../../img/roheline-leht-2.png');
}
```

Comment: Yes! I would like to add that this works on every browser since 2001 :)

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I followed another guide in which they had images as li-s not ul. Anyway, amazing, thanks a lot!